# pdf-renderer runtime exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/pdfview/PDFFile

Tags: java, gwt, noclassdeffounderror, runtimeexception

I've added the pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar as an external JAR to my java GWT project.
While accessing "PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile (buf);" in the following code I get
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/pdfview/PDFFile** runtime exception.

```
private static PDFFile getPdfFile(String filepath) throws Exception{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filepath), "r");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel ();
    ByteBuffer buf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size ());
    PDFFile pdffile1 = new PDFFile(null);
    PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile (buf);    
    return pdfFile;
}
```

What is the reason for this? I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

(I'm trying to run the example from: 
https://github.com/paulhfch/PdfViewer)

Thanks

Comment: In DevMode? once deployed to a servlet container? Is the JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: I've created a GWT project in eclipse. The JAR is in the "Referenced Libraries", I've tried to move it to the WEB-INF/lib dir but I still get the same. I'm kind of new to GWT so I'm not certain what you mean about the servlet container. I'm trying to run the following example:https://github.com/paulhfch/PdfViewer

Answer (score 0):

add the pdf.render library in first in properties--->java build path and then add external jar pdf-render.jar and then apply and close and then check is it present in deployment assembly if yes then there is no issue other wise add in properties-->Deployment assembly I resolved it by that way

Comment: It would be nice if you put some screen shots in this answer.